# Automation error that appears when I try to hide rows

Tags: excel, vba

I have an error message that appears when I run the program below:

```
Sub hidde_row()

For Each cell In Range("H13:H42")
    If cell.Value = 0 Then cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
Next cell

End Sub
```

How to fix this please? (I am a beginner)

> error =  Compile error: Automation error

Answer (score 0):

Runs fine for me, I would add in declared variables to specify what you are trying to reach as well as putting quotation marks around the 0 to ensure formatting is not getting in the way.

```
Sub hide_row()

    Dim ws as worksheet
    Set ws = Activeworkbook.Sheets("Sheet_Name")

        For Each cell In ws.Range("H13:H42")
            If cell.Value = "0" Then 
                cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: @EnzoMarques Did this solve your issue?